# ¿como mejorar esta funcion de busqueda en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Tengo la siguiente funcion que deberían aparecer opciones disponibles para que se carguen los datos de: "nombre, apellido y correo"

Lo que tengo:

```
var getDisplayName = function(customerObject) {

            return customerObject.name || customerObject.surname || customerObject.email;

        }
```

Lo que necesito:

Necesito que me muestre nombre y apellido o nombre o apellido si es que alguno de los dos no está y sino email solamente.

Mi formulario siempre pide minimo nombre y mail como datos obligatorios, pero el newsletter solo mail. o sea mail es el valor que se repite en todos los casos 
pero no quiere decir que el mail, sea igual que el nombre del cliente.

Espero sea clara mi consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuación, te dejo dos opciones para resolver tu problema, en la primera es mucho más claro lo que se hace, y en la segunda está más reducido el código.

```js
var getDisplayName = function(customer) {
    let displayName;

    if (customer.name && customer.surname) {
        displayName = customer.name + ' ' + customer.surname;

    } else if (customer.name || customer.surname) {
        displayName = customer.name || customer.surname;

    } else {
        displayName = customer.email;
    }

    return displayName;
}
```

```js
var getDisplayName = function(customer) {
    return customer.name || customer.surname ? ((customer.name || '') + ' ' + (customer.surname || '')).trim() : customer.email;
}
```